# Mysql 5GB file import stalls (consequently, it is practically failed)

Tags: mysql, import

I am using the Macbook for my develpoment and I need a big file imported to my Mysql DB. I am importing a 4.87GB file to my SQL. I have around 20GB free on the drive. Should be enough? I am importing it through mysql through Mac terminal. It does its thing, goes and then stalls at some import and never continues. Why is this happening? This is the last bit of output after which it just stalls and doesn't output anything after it:

```
Query OK, 14654 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 14654  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 14538 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 14538  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 14472 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 14472  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 14300 rows affected (0.14 sec)
Records: 14300  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 14536 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 14536  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 14580 rows affected (0.14 sec)
Records: 14580  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 14570 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 14570  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 14603 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 14603  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 1633 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1633  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's server's runtime limit, I advise you to control logs of mysql.

If that's the case you can go around this problem by trying to split your dump into more more dumps.
For exemple, you'll have  5 dumps of less then 1 GB rather then  1 big dump of 4.87GB and after restore all of them.

Otherwise you can wait and try again until it completely imports your data(very time-consuming).

Hope this is helpful or gave you new ideas.

Comment: It actually does make sense. However, at the end, what happened is that I waited for an hour and eventually, the import finished the job. I bet if I divide it into smaller pieces (multiple files with fewer insert-s) it would've gone more smoothly.

Comment: If you put my solution (which is to simply wait one hour for the process to finish, even though seemingly nothing happens) in your answer, I will accept it.